# Performance issues in game loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, performance, ipad

I'm developing my first iPad game in Objective-C and Cocoa-Touch and have some performance issues in the game loop. 
Every game object is observed by a `CALayer` which draws the game object on the screen when changes occur. I've seen this design in a [tutorial on Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html) and liked the idea.

In the game loop I use the following code to update the game objects:

```
NSArray *allKeys = [gameObjects allKeys];  

NSLog(@"fps: %.5f; %d game objects", 1.0 / frameDuration, [allKeys count]); // profiling

// update game objects
for (NSString *gameObjectKey in allKeys) {
    [gameObjects willChangeValueForKey:gameObjectKey];

    GameObject *gameObject = [[self gameObjectForKey:gameObjectKey] retain];

    if ([gameObject updateWithTimeInterval:frameDuration]) {
        [self removeGameObjectForKey:gameObjectKey];
    }

    if ([gameObject hasChanges]) {
        [gameObjects didChangeValueForKey:gameObjectKey];
        gameObject.changes = 0; // reset changes
    }

    [gameObject release];
}
```

While this works great for less than 30 game objects, frame rate drops from 30 fps down to 15 for more than 30 game objects.

When I omit the `hasChanges` call and just call `[gameObjects didChangeValueForKey:gameObjectKey];` every single time, I can maintain the 30 frames per second. Why? Is it more expensive to ask a game object for changes than to tell the game objects' dictionary that a value has changed which forces a layer to update itself? Does that make sense?

I also used profiling to find out what exactly causes the performance issues, but I can't really handle the Instruments tools.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your `hasChanges` method on `GameObject` look like? Whatever happens there is what is slowing your code down.

Comment: Also, I've not used CoreAnimation but it sounds like you're writing an arcade game, and while CoreAnimation seems to handle your game so far, its probably not the most efficient framework for the job and might run people's batteries down. For this sort of thing you'll get much better performance from something like Cocos2d.

Comment: @toiletseat: Thanks for your comment. `hasChanges` is equal to `changes > 0`, that couldn't be so expensive, could it?

Comment: @toiletseat: Oh, haven't seen you second comment. Yeah, Cocos2d looks great! But for this simple game (and it is my first) I'd like to stay with CoreAnimation. Do you have an idea of what the problem might be? Is it bad to send a lot of messages in the game loop?

Comment: Not nescessarily, depends what the messages do! I think for this you'll just have to break out Instruments and follow a tutorial on how to profile your app. 90% of the time the bottleneck isn't where you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the retain/release of `gameObject` as it is redundant.

Also, you are calling `willChangeValueForKey`, but not always calling `didChangeValueForKey`, when they should be balanaced, which might be causing the perfomance issue. What is `gameObjects`? Are you sure its not already KVO compliant? Are you sure it needs to be? If so, why? Does the code still work if you remove all the KVO stuff?

Edit...new code:

```
// update game objects
for (NSString *gameObjectKey in allKeys) {      
    GameObject *gameObject = [self gameObjectForKey:gameObjectKey];           

    bool objectDead = [gameObject updateWithTimeInterval:frameDuration];

    if ([gameObject hasChanges]) {
        [gameObjects willChangeValueForKey:gameObjectKey];
        [gameObjects didChangeValueForKey:gameObjectKey];
        gameObject.changes = 0; // reset changes
    }

    if (objectDead) {
        [self removeGameObjectForKey:gameObjectKey];
    }
}
```

Does this work? Redundant retain/release moved and balanced KVO notifications. Its techically bad to have the `willChange` and `didChange` adjacent, but in this case is probably ok.

Comment: 1. I must retain the `gameObject`, because it might be removed from the `gameObjects` dictionary by `[self removeGameObjectForKey:gameObjectKey];` and I won't be able to call `hasChanges` on it.
2. `gameObjects` is a `NSMutableDictionary` containing all game objects.
3. When a game object changes position, the dictionary doesn't automatically fires a KVO-notification.
4. Nope, the code won't work when I remove the KVO stuff. Everything stands still.

Comment: @nubbel, you can remove the retain/release if you swap your two conditionals. Also, make sure your notifications are balanced, even if they are a little 'fake'.

Comment: nice, the code works. Thank you a lot, the trick was really to balance `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`. I didn't want that to do, because the change dictionary in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` would have the same values for "old" and "new". But in my case, it's OK.